# How to create a play again button in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

So i created space invaders with pygame and wanted to create a Quit and play again button when the player died. The quit button works but the play again button isn't working. I have not used a def for the button instead i have made it inside the code.This is my code:

```py
import pygame
import random
import math


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))              # CREATING SCREEN
background = pygame.image.load('background.jpg')

pygame.display.set_caption("Space invaders")              # Title of the game

icon = pygame.image.load('spaceship.png')                 # A variable for the icon of the game
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)                            # to display the icon

player_icon = pygame.image.load('space-invaders.png')     # A variable for player's icon
playerX = 365                                             # X coordinate
playerY = 500                                              # Y coordinate
playerX_change = 0
def player(x, y):
    screen.blit(player_icon,(x, y))                     # Function to display player_icon {there is supposed to be a comma after image name}

enemy_icon = []
enemyX = []
enemyY = []
enemyX_change = []
enemyY_change =[]
num_of_enemies = 5

for i in range(num_of_enemies):
    enemy_icon.append(pygame.image.load('alien.png'))            # A variable for enemy's's icon
    enemyX.append(random.randint(0,736))                          # X coordinate
    enemyY.append(random.randint(50 ,150))                      # Y coordinate
    enemyX_change.append(2)
    enemyY_change.append(40)


def enemy(x, y, i):
    screen.blit(enemy_icon[i], (x, y))              # Function to display enemy_icon {there is supposed to be a comma after image name}


bullet_icon = pygame.image.load('bullet.png')            # A variable for enemy's's icon
bulletX = 0                                       # X coordinate
bulletY = 480                                     # Y coordinate
bulletX_change = 0
bulletY_change = 5
bullet_state = "ready"

score_value = 0
font = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',32)
textX = 10
textY = 10

red = (200, 0, 0)
brigth_red = (255,0 ,0)
green = (0, 200, 0)
brigth_green = (0, 255, 0)
blue = (0, 0, 255)
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0, 0 ,0)

def show_score(x,y):
    score = font.render('Score: ' + str(score_value), True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(score, (x, y))

over_text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',128)
def game_over_text():
    over_text = font.render('GAME OVER !!' , True, (255, 255, 255))
    screen.blit(over_text, (300, 150))

def on_button(x,y,text =''):
    button_text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf', 5)
    button_text = font.render(text, True, (black))
    screen.blit(button_text, ((x + 5), (y + 5)))


def bullet(x, y):
    screen.blit(bullet_icon, (x, y))             # Function to display enemy_icon {there is supposed to be a comma after image name}

def fire_bullet(x,y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bullet_icon, (x+19, y+10))

def iscoalision(bulletX,bulletY,enemyX,enemyY):
    distance = math.sqrt(math.pow(enemyX - bulletX,2) + math.pow(enemyY-bulletY,2))
    if distance < 25:
        return True
    else:
        return False

running = True
game_state = "not working"


while running :

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))                         # to fill the screen with some color RGB = (red,green,blue)
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            round = 11

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:          # If arrow key is pressed change value of playerX_change
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                playerX_change = -3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:                   # If arrow key is released stop changing value of playerX_change
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                playerX_change = 0

    playerX += playerX_change                    #player movement
    if playerX <= 0:                             #(The boundary)
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 736:                         #(     "      )
        playerX = 736

    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        if enemyY[i] > 440:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if 100 + 200 > mouse[0] > 100 and 300 + 50 > mouse[1] > 300:    # This is where i try to make play again button        
                    
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, brigth_green, (100, 300, 200, 50))    # inside the bracket(x-axis , y-axis , width, hieght)
                if click[0] == 1:                                             #the tuple for clicks is (0,0,0) [0] = left click ,[1]= middle click. if clicked [0] or [1] or [2] = 1
                    pass                                
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, (100, 300, 200, 50))
            on_button(100,300,'play again?')

            if 500+ 200 >mouse[0] > 500 and 300 +50 >mouse[1] > 300:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, brigth_red, (500, 300, 200, 50))
                if click[0] == 1:
                    running = False
                    break

            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, red, (500, 300, 200, 50))
            on_button((500 + 50),(300 + 5),"I QUIT")

        enemyX[i] += enemyX_change[i]                      #enemy movement
        if enemyX[i] <= 0:                              #(The boundary two and fro movement)
            enemyX_change[i] = 2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]
        elif enemyX[i] >= 736:                          #(               "                 )
            enemyX_change[i] = -2
            enemyY[i] += enemyY_change[i]

        coalision = iscoalision(bulletX, bulletY, enemyX[i], enemyY[i])

        if coalision:
            bullet_state = "ready"
            bulletY = 480
            score_value += 1
            enemyX[i] = random.randint(0, 736)
            enemyY[i] = random.randint(50, 150)
        enemy(enemyX[i], enemyY[i], i)

    if bulletY <= 0:
        bullet_state = "ready"
        bulletY = 480
    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX,bulletY)
        bulletY -= bulletY_change

    player(playerX, playerY)
    show_score(textX, textY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Till now i have tried to put the entire while loop i an if condition that if condition is satisfied then run the while loop but that isn't working. I've also tried to put the entire code in a def and call out the def when i needed to play again and that worked but that made the bullets bug which i couldn't fix. Here is the play agin button and function.

```py
    for i in range(num_of_enemies):
        if enemyY[i] > 440:
            for j in range(num_of_enemies):
                enemyY[j] = 2000
            game_over_text()
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            click = pygame.mouse.get_pressed()
            if 100 + 200 > mouse[0] > 100 and 300 + 50 > mouse[1] > 300:           
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, brigth_green, (100, 300, 200, 50))     
                if click[0] == 1:                                         
                    pass
```

for now i filled the place for the button function with a pass. Hope this much info helps.

Comment: Why can't you simply restart the script with something like `os.execl()`?

Comment: @KingDuken well i am a new programmer so i didn't know u can do that .

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, make your code object oriented. If you don't know what that is, there are plenty of tutorials on youtube, but just looking at your code, I can see that you are going to run into a bunch of headache in the future if you continue without any type of classes and objects. You should make a class for player, enemy and bullets and then define their attributes and call methods on them such as move() or draw().

To answer you question, you can create a simple button class:

```
class Buttons(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, colour1, text='', func=None, arg=None):  # pink buttons
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.colour1 = colour1
        self.text = text
        self.func = func
        self.arg = arg

    def draw(self, win):  # draws centralised buttons and text
        font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsans', 30, True)
        text = font.render(self.text, 1, colours["black"])
        pygame.draw.rect(win, self.colour1,
                         (int(self.x - self.width // 2), int(self.y - self.height // 2), int(self.width), int(self.height)))
        win.blit(text, (int(self.x - text.get_width() // 2), int(self.y - text.get_height() // 2)))

    def isover(self, pos):  # detects if mouse positions is above buttons'
        if self.x < pos[0] < (self.x + self.width) and self.y < pos[1] < (self.y + self.height):
            return True
        return False

    def isclicked(self, pos):  # pos here is mouse position
        if self.isover(pos):
            if self.arg is not None:
                self.func(*self.arg):
            else:
                self.func():

def quit(your_quit_args):
    # this is your quit function. You might want to close any files, etc before quitting

def play_again(your_play_again_args):
    # here, you should reset all values, clear queues, lists etc
```

With that then, to create a button, all you would need to do is just create a new button object:

```
# use the x, y, width, height, colour and text you want
btn_play_again = Button(x, y, width, height, colour, text=your_text, func=quit, args=your_quit_args)
btn_quit = Button(x, y, width, height, colour, text=your_text, func=play_again, args=your_play_again_args)
```

the above will create the button objects, but you have to actually draw them and check if they are clicked, which you should do in your main loop:

```
while running:
    # everything else
    btn_quit.draw(screen)
    btn_play_again.draw(screen)
    pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    btn_quit.isclicked(pos)
    btn_play_Again.draw(pos)

    pygame.display.update()
```

Note, if you have many buttons, it may be worth to put them all in a button list and iterate through it to avoid repeating code.